# What is the syntax to match on a reference to an enum?

Tags: rust

It seems like every introductory document for Rust's [enum types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/enums.html) explains how to [match](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/match.html) on an enum object that you *own*, but what if you do not own the enum object and you just have a reference to it that you want to match against?  I don't know what the syntax would be.

Here is some code where I attempt to match on a reference to an enum:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::io::prelude::*;

pub enum Animal {
    Cat(String),
    Dog,
}

impl fmt::Display for Animal {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Animal::Cat(c) => f.write_str("c"),
            Animal::Dog => f.write_str("d"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p: Animal = Animal::Cat("whiskers".to_owned());
    println!("{}", p);
}
```

The [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=373dbfb15757f49f65082e29ba724a47&version=stable&backtrace=0) gives errors on the first two cases of the match when trying to compile it:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |             Animal::Cat(c) => f.write_str("c"),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &Animal, found enum `Animal`
   |
   = note: expected type `&Animal`
   = note:    found type `Animal`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             Animal::Dog => f.write_str("d"),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &Animal, found enum `Animal`
   |
   = note: expected type `&Animal`
   = note:    found type `Animal`
```

How can I change that code to get it to compile?  I tried adding ampersands in lots of different places without any luck.  Is it even possible to match on a reference to an enum?

Comment: It's on the [Rust roadmap](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-roadmap/issues/24) to improve the situation here.

Comment: And as of Rust 1.26, the situation has improved, see [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51111291/1026).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of Rust 1.26, the idiomatic way is *the way that you originally wrote it* [because `match` ergonomics have been improved](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html):

```
use std::fmt;

pub enum Animal {
    Cat(String),
    Dog,
}

impl fmt::Display for Animal {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Animal::Cat(_) => f.write_str("c"),
            Animal::Dog => f.write_str("d"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p: Animal = Animal::Cat("whiskers".to_owned());
    println!("{}", p);
}
```

Comment: I found a few extra subtleties by playing around:

1. You can keep `ref` in front of the inner value `c`, it will do the same as without (as long as you remove the `&` in front of the enum variant).
2. If you keep `&` in front of the enum variant `Cat` but remove `ref c`, it will try to move/copy the inner value `c`! For a borrowed content it can't move out, and will fail to compile.
3. You can also skip `&mut` and `ref mut` in `&mut Enum::Variant(ref mut value)`. You must still write `*value = new_value`.
And sorry for the bad formatting due to comment limitations.

Comment: Found an example in the Rust Book (not mut though):
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html#reference-cycles-can-leak-memory Listing 15-25

Comment: But why ? Is there an explanation for that rule ?

Comment: @chylli updated with a link to [the RFC that make the changes](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: What do we do if we the Dog variant is say Dog(u32), and I want to write the number to f as well in this case?

Comment: @Jay `Dog(v) => write!(f, “blah {}”, v),`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html

Comment: Thanks, apparently my problem was with the [or pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819390/difficulty-aggregating-matches-with)

Answer (score 27):

**Edit: Please see Shepmaster's answer for the latest idiom**

The idiomatic way would be

```
match *self {
    Animal::Cat(ref c) => f.write_str("c"),
    Animal::Dog => f.write_str("d"),
}
```

You can  use `_` instead of `ref c` to silence the "unused" warning.

Comment: Or `..` to ignore multiple values.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and the answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36590693/86381) where each branch of the match is prefaced by `&`?

Comment: @ehdv I wouldn't think so, but I haven't compared the generated assembly yet.

Comment: I've seen at least on one occasion code where the other answer would compile fine, but this one would complain that "cannot move out of borrowed content".

Comment: How do you reference the inner type c in the first match branch arm?

Answer (score 14):

I figured it out thanks to helpful compiler messages:

```
match self {
    &Animal::Cat(ref c) => f.write_str("c"),
    &Animal::Dog => f.write_str("d"),
}
```