# Difficulty aggregating matches with |

Tags: rust, match

I'm trying to pack columnar data so that it can be sent to a server.

I wanted to be able to pass any suitable vector to the sending function, so I did this (brief version):

```rust
enum Column {
    Short(Vec<i16>),
    Int(Vec<i32>),
}

impl Column {
    fn as_bytes(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        use Column::*; // weird
        match self {
            Short(vec) => unsafe { (vec.align_to::<u8>()).1 }, //why the ::?
            Int(vec) => unsafe { (vec.align_to::<u8>()).1 },
        }
    }
}
```

This works ok. However, if I rewrite the match with an or pipe:

```rust
impl Column {
    fn as_bytes_succinct(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        use Column::*;

        match self {
            Short(vec) | Int(vec) => unsafe { (vec.align_to::<u8>()).1 },
        }
    }
}
```

I get

> expected `i16`, found `i32`

How/Why is the brief writing different from the explicit one?

Comment: Within the branch does `vec` have to conform to a single type?

Comment: No, I want to convert it depending on it's type, it just seems `align_to` does the job for most vector types I need

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure Rust is cool with `vec` being one of several types within a single branch. It's going to want to compile that code one way, and one way only. In the other cases the code may look identical, but the compiled versions are going to be very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust is a statically typed language, so every object has a known type at compile-time. Your match in the last example is equivalent to the following code:

```rust
let vec: Vec<???> = match self {
    Short(v) | Int(v) => v,
};

unsafe { vec.align_to() }.1
```

What type type should `vec` have then? Moreover, there are 2 different paths for `align_to`, i.e. `<[i16]>::align_to` and `<[i32]>::align_to`, which may have a different implementation with a [`specialization`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) feature.

Comment: I think I understand. I thought there was some form of generics involved when you're matching, it's just weird to write the same line over and over. Can you name or point me to the ??? syntax? I can't find it

Comment: It just a *placeholder*, there is no such syntax, used it for the reference only. Valid equivalent syntax would be `Vec<_>` (though still compiles with an error).

Comment: Perhaps my design is flawed. I want to the user to be able to pass columns of different types, according to the database schema, and the method will pack and send them. So thought I'll use `columns: Vec<Column>`, can't figure out something better