# Why does destructuring a borrowed Enum require dereferencing its fields?

Tags: rust, reference, pattern-matching, borrow-checker, borrowing

Consider the following snippet:

```rust
use std::fmt;

enum TestEnum {
    StructMem {value: i32, is_valid: bool},
    RandoMem,
}

impl fmt::Display for TestEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        use TestEnum::*;
        match self {
            StructMem {value, is_valid} => {
                if *is_valid { // Why dereference is_valid ?
                    write!(f, "f")?
                }
                write!(f, "{:?}", value)
            }
            RandoMem => {
                f.write_str("Random")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I need to dereference `is_valid` in the `if` statement?

**EDIT:** This question [What is the syntax to match on a reference to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36590549/4126652) seems to be dealing with a similar situation, but the answers are all focused on solving the specific issue (which does not involve a struct) and are not explaining the ownership/binding semantics.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51111291/9716597) of the question [What is the syntax to match on a reference to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590549/what-is-the-syntax-to-match-on-a-reference-to-an-enum) help?

Comment: @L.F. nope, the question is pretty similar and deals with the same situation, but the particular necessity for dereferencing is not really explained in any of the answers

Comment: Indeed, the explanation is in the [match ergonomics RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html) referred to by the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to the `match` or the `enum` but due to the signature of `fmt()`, which takes `self` as a reference (`&self` instead of `self`, if ownership was taken).

The `match self`, therefore, already refers to a borrowed instance of `TestEnum` and the match-arm `StructMem {value, is_valid}` binds via references (`&i32`, and `&bool`). This is why `is_valid` ends up being a `&bool`, not a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

When you pattern match a reference and de-structure it you can only get references of the inner members, otherwise you'd be moving the inner members out of an immutable reference which would violate Rust's ownership rules. Here's a simpler example:

```rust
struct Container(Vec<i32>);

fn get_inner_vec(c: &Container) -> &Vec<i32> {
    // v MUST BE a reference
    // otherwise this destructing would somehow be moving the Vec
    // outside of an immutable borrow of Container
    let Container(v) = c;
    v
}
```